# useState in while cause infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, loops

I trying to make Blackjack game in React. A bot has got 2 cards at start. If user stands, and bots card value is less than 17, it should draw addictional card, but then program cause infinite loop. This is my code:

```
  const [playerCards, setPlayerCards] = useState<Card[]>([]);
  const shuffledDeck = shuffleDeck(deck);
  const [dealerCards, setDealerCards] = useState<Card[]>([]);
```

```
const shuffleDeck = (deck: Card[]): Card[] => {
  for (let i = deck.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [deck[i], deck[j]] = [deck[j], deck[i]];
  }
  return deck;
};
```

```
  const handleStand = () => {
    if (gameState === 'playing') {
      console.log(shuffledDeck[playerCards.length + dealerCards.length]);
      while(getHandValue(dealerCards) < 17) {
        setDealerCards([
          ...dealerCards,
          shuffledDeck[playerCards.length + dealerCards.length],
        ]);
      }
    }
    let dealerHandValue = getHandValue(dealerCards);
    const playerHandValue = getHandValue(playerCards);
    if (dealerHandValue > 21 || dealerHandValue < playerHandValue) {
      setGameState('won');
      setPlayerBalance(playerBalance + currentBet);
    } else if (dealerHandValue > playerHandValue) {
      setGameState('lost');
      setPlayerBalance(playerBalance - currentBet);
    } else {
      setGameState('tied');
    }
  };
```

```
const getHandValue = (cards: Card[]): number => {
  let value = 0;
  let numAces = 0;
  for (const card of cards) {
    if (card.rank === Rank.Ace) {
      numAces++;
    } else if (card.rank === 'J' || card.rank === 'K' || card.rank === 'Q') {
      value += 10;
    } else {
      value += Number(card.rank);
    }
  }
  while (numAces > 0) {
    if (value + 11 > 21) {
      value += 1;
    } else {
      value += 11;
    }
    numAces--;
  }
  return value;
};
```

The goal is to make bot draw a cards until value of his cards will be at least 17.

Comment: there is an issue with setDealerCards,
this will not add cards
```javascript
setDealerCards([
          ...dealerCards,
          shuffledDeck[playerCards.length + dealerCards.length],
        ]);
```

instead, do this
```javascript
setDealerCards([
          ...dealerCards,
          ...shuffledDeck[playerCards.length + dealerCards.length],
        ]);
```
add spread operator before shuffledDeck[playerCards.length || dealerCards.length]

Comment: Can you share your code via sandbox to find out the issue ?

Comment: @ShubhdeepChhabra nah, that's not a problem. I'm adding a cards for playerCards by this way and everything works fine. The only difference is that I'm just adding one card there, everytime when user clicks "Hit" button. In handleStand function everythink works fine if I use ````if(getHandValue(dealerCards) < 17)```` instead of ````while(getHandValue(dealerCards) < 17)````. Using 'while' or any other loop cause inifite loop.

Comment: I also edited code because there was ````if(getHandValue(dealerCards) < 17)```` - should be while because this is the problem.

Comment: How is `handleStand` being used? is it an `onClick` function or something else?
Every time you set a state it causes a re-render to the component which may result in triggering `handleStand` perhaps.
But anyway, I would suggest making a new variable `newDealerCards`, spread `dealerCards` in it, then add what you need to this variable inside the while loop and set it to the state after the while has finished.

Comment: @Ben yes, handleStand work as onClick function. I will try this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, using `setDealerCards` inside the `while` loop can be problematic. Setting the state causes a re-render to the component and may trigger the function again depending on it's use.
Another problem may be that since React schedules it's updates you may not get the most updated state every time you set the state again in the `while` loop.

So this might help

```
  const handleStand = () => {
    let newDealerCards = [...dealerCards];
    if (gameState === 'playing') {
      while(getHandValue(newDealerCards) < 17) {
             newDealerCards = 
             [...newDealerCards, shuffledDeck[playerCards.length + newDealerCards.length]];
      }
      setDealerCards(newDealerCards);
    }
    let dealerHandValue = getHandValue(newDealerCards);
    const playerHandValue = getHandValue(playerCards);
    if (dealerHandValue > 21 || dealerHandValue < playerHandValue) {
      setGameState('won');
      setPlayerBalance(playerBalance + currentBet);
    } else if (dealerHandValue > playerHandValue) {
      setGameState('lost');
      setPlayerBalance(playerBalance - currentBet);
    } else {
      setGameState('tied');
    }
  };
```

We make the new `newDealerCards` variable to spread `dealerCards` state, we then do the `while` loop with your condition and update `newDealerCards` accordingly. When we're done, only then we set the state again with the updated variable we made and thus we avoid calling `setDealerCards` multiple times inside the `while` loop.